# htaccess Rewrite Rule for 301 Redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm horrible with regex/htaccess and I need help to make this 301 rewrite rule:

Transform:

*domain.com/something/something/fixed_text-name*

to

*domain.com/fixed_text/name*

**Note**: 'fixed_text' is always the same.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to create pretty URL's? meaning is `domain.com/fixed_text/name` a real directory or not?

Comment: and What is `something/something/` supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/(fixed_text)-([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```